# How to uncompress a password protected zip file?

Tags: password, zip, astro-file-manager

I have a password protected zip file, but ASTRO does not let me enter a password. What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install [Dual File Manager](http://www.appbrain.com/app/dual-file-manager/it.medieval.dualfm). This program lets you unzip password protected files.

Comment: Is this app an official one? E.g. is it on the Google Play Store?

Answer (score 2):

Try [ArchiDroid](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.ais.archidroid) and it will do your job... It extracts password-protected RAR, ZIP, TAR, GZIP, BZIP2 and 7zip files... amazingly it is free... Other apps didn't work for me but this one works like a charm :)

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

[B1 Free Archiver](http://www.appbrain.com/app/b1-free-archiver-zip-rar-unzip/org.b1.android.archiver#descriptionsection) works good for unzipping files and password protected files.

**How to uncompress a password protected zip file?** 
It's very simple, just tap two times on your archive and enter the password.

Comment: This is your second answer touting this app. What's your affiliation?

Comment: From the first answer: "I was helping to translate this soft as a volunteer at CrowdIn translation platform, so I know it well enough to describe it to others."  Your answer here is definitely more suited to the question, Kim, so it can stay -- just beware of how it looks when a new user shows up and starts hawking a particular piece of software!